# win32gui.GetPixel() not working: pywintypes.error: (0, 'GetPixel', 'No error message is available')

Tags: python, win32gui, pysimplegui

In my own pysimplegui program, and others, every time I use GetPixel, I get the error: pywintypes.error: (0, 'GetPixel', 'No error message is available').

```
while True:                             # The Event Loop
event, values = window.read()
hwnd = win32gui.FindWindow(None, 'Window that stays open')
rgbint2rgbtuple(win32gui.GetPixel(hwnd, 100, 100))

print(event, values)
if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Exit':
    break
```

the only time it didn't crash was with google chrome, but it gave the wrong RGB values. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use following way the get value of pixel,

```py
import win32ui

w = win32ui.FindWindow(None, 'Window that stays open')
dc = w.GetWindowDC()
color = dc.GetPixel(100, 100)
```

Should check the case if window 'Window that stays open' not found or with wrong title. confirm what title of your window by following code. Also confirm point(x, y) in your window.

```py
import win32gui

def enumWindowFunc(hwnd, windowList):
    text = win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd)
    className = win32gui.GetClassName(hwnd)
    if text and className != "IME":
        print(repr(text), repr(className))

win32gui.EnumWindows(enumWindowFunc, [])
```

Comment: So I did that, but I still have the same issues. Returns 0 for Google Chrome, and fails for pretty much anything else :\ "win32ui.error: GetPixel failed" Thanks for replying

Comment: Update as above.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. So I know the window is there and that I'm using the correct name. I ran your code and found my window in the list. In my current test, I do FindWindow('example'), then I print the dimensions of it using GetWindowRect(hwnd), but then when I try to run GetPixel on the window, I get a crash. The only time it doesn't crash is when I run GetPixel on GetActiveWindow()

Comment: Okay, I must have been doing something dumb because I just tried again and it works... Lol I'm so sorry thank you for the help.